# Как получить значение из input

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

Есть input, в которое вводится число, изначально поле input получает значение из сервера, через selenium я нахожу этот input, и когда вызываю getText(), выводится пустая строка, как получить число из этого input. На странице используется websocket соединение. И если смотреть через инспектор, то в input нет никакого значения.

Comment: Может `getValue()` или `getValues()`?

Comment: Можно попробовать

Comment: getValue или getValues не работает, просто потому что таких методов нет

Comment: `getProperty('value')`? Увы я не смог найти список методов.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую так

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло, getAttribite()

Comment: А можете подсказать какой атрибут надо изменить у тега select чтобы изменить выбранное значение

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию getAttribute('value')